# WPF Popup inside a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need a WPF Popup inside a DataTemplate, something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Name="MyTextboxBrief" Text="{Binding TextBrief}"/>
                    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyTextboxBrief}" Placement="Center">
                        <TextBox Name="MyTextboxVerbose" Text="{Binding TextVerbose}"/>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But, this Popup should behave like this:

1. it must scroll together with relevant ItemsControl item
2. when app window is minimized - it shouldn't stay visible on desktop
3. it will be taller than ItemsControl, its content mustn't be clipped, but it mustn't change ItemsControl height
4. it will be wider than relevant ItemsControl item - but it shouldn't shift other ItemsControl items to the left or to the right

I have a strong feeling that I should somehow use ComboBox template - but I don't understand how to get it's Popup behavior

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `Popup` will help you here, nor `ComboBox`. See if this helps you any further:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextboxBrief" Text="{Binding TextBrief}" />


        <!-- You might want to bind visibility against
            some kind of property -->
        <Canvas >
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                 <!--In case you want to move--> 
                <TranslateTransform Y="-5" />
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>

            <Border Width="100" Height="20" Background="Black">
                <TextBlock Text="Test" />
            </Border>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```